# Is there a 3d fibonacci sequence?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Is there 3d equivalent to the fibonacci sequence? I see pictures of the golden spiral and was wondering if there was a similar kind of sequence that would fill up 3 dimensional space. I was looking at the Romanesco broccoli, which is a 3d shape, but you can only see the spiral from looking at it in a particular way.

Comment: Is the Fibonacci sequence 2D.?

Comment: Golden dragon fractal is what the OP is talking about  . . . I think.

Comment: I think OP is talking about this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Padovan sequence has a 3-D analogue that fills the space with prisms that grow in linear dimension as the sequence. That's all I remember of the top of my head.

[image: Padovan 3D Tessellation]